Vertically scroll multiple plots in Tkinter
I would like to draw multiple plots with Matplotlib, add them to a Tkinter frame (stack them one below the other), and be able to scroll vertically between the plots.
Each plot shold fill the x-direction, and have a minimum y-height, so that if the total height of the multiple plots is above the height of the window, the scroll should be enabled.
I have found a way to scroll a single large figure (made of multiple subplots), but I am constrained to use a library which cannot produce subplots, so my idea was to stack the single plots one below the other, considering them as Tkinter widgets.
So far, I have the following, but as you can see the scrollbar is present but doesn't work.
Any insight would be useful.
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

f = Figure()
a = f.add_subplot(111)

g = Figure()
b = g.add_subplot(111)

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config()
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

middle = Frame(canvas, bg="yellow")
middle.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, fill="both")

canvas_1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, middle)
canvas_1.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill="both")
canvas_1.draw()

bottom = Frame(canvas, bg="blue")
bottom.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, fill="both")

canvas_2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(g, bottom)
canvas_2.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill="both")
canvas_2.draw()

root.mainloop()

which produces:



Just add each frame to subplot(s)

@toyotaSupra could you please elaborate a little more?

Use canvas.create_window() to put the frame middle into the canvas instead of middle.pack(...).  Also put the two plots into same frame middle.

Using middle.pack() to put frame middle (same for frame bottom) will not activate the scrollbar.
You need to put frame middle into the canvas using canvas.create_window() instead and put the two plots into frame middle (so frame bottom can be removed).
Below is the modified code:
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

f = Figure()
a = f.add_subplot(111)

g = Figure()
b = g.add_subplot(111)

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='#FFFFFF', width=700, height=700,
                highlightthickness=0)

vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

middle = Frame(canvas, bg="yellow")
# put the frame using .create_window()
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=middle, anchor='nw')

# put the two plots into same frame "middle"
canvas_1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, middle)
canvas_1.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canvas_1.draw()

canvas_2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(g, middle)
canvas_2.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canvas_2.draw()

# update canvas scrollregion option whenever the frame is resized
middle.bind(
    '<Configure>',
    lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
)

root.mainloop()

Result:

